# Attempting to compile from source - error making libGLU for libstage

Tags: ros, build-from-source, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to build ROS Hydro from source on my laptop, running Ubuntu 13.10.  However, I keep running into a compile error with openGL.

```
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'stage'
==> Building with env: '/home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/stage/install'
==> make -j8 -l8 in '/home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/stage/install'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so', needed by `libstage/libstage.so.4.1.1'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [libstage/CMakeFiles/stage.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'stage': 
  Command '/home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/stage && /home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

Trying the commands given to reproduce the error gives the following output:

```
alec@Ares:~/ros_catkin_ws$ cd /home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/stage && sudo /home/alec/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've looked up the issue in a more general scope, not focused on ROS, and most of the solutions involved adding a missing symlink (though the most recent posts about a failure to compile with libGLU.so are dealing with Ubuntu 11, so it's not exactly up-to-date), but checking the file locations themselves showed that the symlinks were all there.  I also tried purging and reinstalling the openGL drivers, which resulted in the same error.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139186/attempting-to-compile-from-source---error-making-libglu-for-libstage/) by [Alec Thompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/13211/alec-thompson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem once I installed the nvidia drivers on my notebook but there was actually a missing link. So for me the following resolved the compiling problem

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Hope that this works for you as well.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) with karma: 115 on 2014-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2